# Compiler keeps showing the error that string and birthday dont name a type, why is this happening? ps ignore the repetitions

Tags: c++

main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "birthday.h"
#include "alex.h"


int main() {

   birthday obji(12,12,1990);
   alex namess("alex the great" , obji);
   namess.printinfo();

}
```

birthday.h

```
#ifndef BIRTHDAY_H
#define BIRTHDAY_H


class birthday
{
   public:
    birthday(int a, int b, int c);

        void printdate();
    private:
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;

};


#endif // BIRTHDAY_H
```

birthday.cpp

```
#include "birthday.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

birthday::birthday(int a, int b, int c)
: int month = a, int day = b , int year = c;
{

}

void birthday::printdate(){

   cout << a << "/" << b << "/" << c;
    }
```

alex.h

```
#ifndef ALEX_H
#define ALEX_H
#include <string>
#include "birthday.h"

class alex
{
    public:
        alex( string x, birthday objective);
        void printinfo();

    private:
        string name;
        birhday obj;
};

#endif
```

alex.cpp

```
#include "alex.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "birthday.h"

alex::alex()

: name(x) , obj(objective)

{

}
alex::printinfo(){
cout << name << "was born on";
obj.printdate;
}
```

so, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg

so, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
so, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
so, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggso, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggso, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggso, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggso, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggso, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggvso, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggso, i am learning compostion in c++ and i was trying to use the birthday class inside of the alex class but this error keeps popping up continuosly. anyone knows whats wrong with the code? any help will be appreciated. gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg" - *Don't* do that, please.

Comment: @JesperJuhl i cant do anything about that apparently stackoverflor demands a very detailed and lengthy question i just cant. i wrote what i needed to write and thats that.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in file alex.h

```
#ifndef ALEX_H
#define ALEX_H
#include <string>
#include "birthday.h"

class alex
{
    public:
        alex( string x, birthday objective);
        void printinfo();

    private:
        std::string name;
        birthday obj;
};
```

Here you forgotten to std::

> ```
>         std::string name;
> ```

Here birthday is wrongly typed (birhday).

> ```
>         birthday obj;
> ```

Comment: i had before wrore the somewhat same code without the std::string name and it worked perfectly, why is it showing this error ? is it because i havent included the standard library??

Comment: main.cpp file compiles without std:: because you do using namespace in this file. But when you compile alex.cpp you need it. The best option is dont add using namespace std; in header files and declare objects specifying namespace::class